# Function template as friend of class template

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In the following example I want the function template `get()` to be a friend of the class template `any_of`. I think it is obviuos the only the instantiation of `get` with the type-parameters as `any_of` should be a friend. The index `I` should not be free.

```
template<typename T, typename... TT> struct any_of;

template<auto I, typename... TT> auto& get(const any_of<TT...>&);

template<typename T, typename... TT>
struct any_of {
    template<auto I> friend auto& get<I, T, TT...>(const any_of<T, TT...>&);
    
    any_of(const T& first, const TT&... rest) : mData{first, rest...}{}  
private:
    std::tuple<T, TT...> mData;
};
template<auto I, typename... TT>
auto& get(const any_of<TT...>& a) {
    return std::get<I>(a.mData);
}    
template<typename L, typename... TT>
bool operator==(const L& lhs, const any_of<TT...>& rhs) {
    return [&]<auto... II>(std::index_sequence<II...>){
        return ((lhs == get<II>(rhs)) || ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TT)>{});
}
```

I like to achive that all `get<N, char, char>` are friends to `any_of<char, char>` but not to `any_of<int, char>`.

The above try gives a compilation error  `invalid use of template-id 'get<I, T, TT ...>' in declaration of primary template`

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/8b69eazPT

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://onlinegdb.com/-uLYyO-iD

Comment: Surely you have to instantiate.

Comment: Sorry, I edited to above example.

Comment: "partial specialization of the function template" - Partial specialization of functions is not allowed. Did you mean partial specialization of `any_of`, for which some form of `get` function is friend?

Comment: Arrgh, yes. That's it, I think. Partial specialization of unction templates isn't possible. But then arises the question, why the error message didn't mention that?

Comment: Or is there another way to achieve my goal? Well, introduce an member function would be simple possible. But the original question remains.

Comment: I edited the title and the contents because the term partial-specialization was misleading I think.

Answer (score 0):

A (function or class) template can be a friend, and a specialization of a template (whether instantiated or explicitly declared) can be a friend, but the only way to make a **larger** subset of specializations be friends is to befriend a member of a dependent type:

```
template<int> struct B;
class A {
  template<int I> friend void B<I>::f();
};
```

(You can’t even befriend a declared partial specialization.)  You can use that approach here by defining a **helper** class template to hold `get`’s implementation for `any_of`, but you might as well make the whole corresponding specialized a friend, and it’s not much different from adding a member function for `get` to call anyway.